# Convert int32 to bytes List in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert int32 into bytes array.

specifically i want to convert  477 to bytes array like [el1,el2,el3,el4]
i tried `utf8.encode(477.toString());`
and got [52, 55, 55]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to create a byte list (`Uint8list`), then view the underlying buffer as a 32-bit integer list (`Int32List`) and store the integer there. That will allow you to read back the bytes.

```
import "dart:typed_data";

Uint8List int32bytes(int value) =>
    Uint8List(4)..buffer.asInt32List()[0] = value;
```

This will store the integer using the platform's byte ordering. If you want a particular byte ordering, you can use a `ByteData` view instead, which allows writing bytes in any endianness and position:

```
Uint8List int32BigEndianBytes(int value) =>
    Uint8List(4)..buffer.asByteData().setInt32(0, value, Endian.big);
```

Comment: Nice, very clean solution.